# Android Navigation Component: back button pressed multiple times before it closes the app

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, back-stack, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a navigation graph with 4 fragments. Each fragment is a stand-alone view: can only navigate to the next fragment, but never navigate back to the previous one.

**Expected behaviour:**
Pressing back button should close the app. If the fragment has a pager, then the back button should navigate back the pager until it reaches index 0, then after that should close the app.

1. SplashFragment: a splash screen
2. LanguageFragment: a view to setup language
3. BoardingFragment: has a pager and serves as an on-boarding flow
4. StartupFragment: has a pager and serves as an initial set up flow

**The Problem:**
All works fine from Frag1 (SplashFragment) to Frag3 (BoardingFragment). But once navigated to Frag4 (StartupFragment) and pager is at index 0, I still have to press back button 7 times before it closes the app. No crashes nor error thrown.

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/splash_nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/splash_fragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/splash_fragment"
        android:name=".ui.fragments.SplashFragment"
        android:label="fragment_splash"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_splash" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/splash_to_lang_action"
            app:destination="@id/language_fragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/splash_fragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/language_fragment"
        android:name=".ui.fragments.LanguageFragment"
        android:label="fragment_language"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_language" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/lang_to_boarding_action"
            app:destination="@id/boarding_fragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/splash_nav_graph"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/boarding_fragment"
        android:name=".ui.fragments.BoardingFragment"
        android:label="fragment_boarding"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_boarding" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/boarding_to_startup_action"
            app:destination="@id/startup_fragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/splash_nav_graph"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/startup_fragment"
        android:name=".ui.fragments.StartupFragment"
        android:label="fragment_startup"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_startup" />

</navigation>
```

In SplashFragment:

```kotlin
// navigate after an action
navController.navigate(
                    R.id.splash_to_lang_action, null, null,
                    FragmentNavigatorExtras(binding.logo to binding.logo.transitionName)
                )
```

In LanguageFragment:

```kotlin
// navigate after an action
navController.navigate(R.id.lang_to_boarding_action)
```

In BoardingFragment:

```kotlin
// navigate after an action
navController.navigate(R.id.boarding_to_startup_action)

// manage back-press for pager
activity?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.addCallback {
            if (binding.uspPager.currentItem != 0) binding.uspPager.currentItem--
            else {
                isEnabled = false
                activity?.onBackPressed()
            }
        }
```

In StartupFragment:

```kotlin
// manage back-press for pager
activity?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.addCallback {
            if (binding.uspPager.currentItem != 0) binding.uspPager.currentItem--
            else {
                isEnabled = false
                activity?.onBackPressed()
            }
        }
```

I appreciate any help to the max. Thanks in advance.

Comment: in the `BoardingFragment` can you try BoardingFragmentDirections.boardingToStartupAction().also{ findNavController().navigate(it) } instead of using the action id

Comment: Thanks for your response @HamzaSharuf. Im not passing any argument with the action, so i dont get `BoardingFragmentDirections` generated. 

Any idea of what could be blocking the back button? btw the flow from `LanguageFragment ` to `BoardingFragment` is the same, but the back button work as expected